# Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and have been following on online tutorial, which involves creating a simple blog site. I am at the point in the project of adding tests for the controllers and models. When I attempt to run the posts_controller_test.rb, I get the following error:

```
Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    app/views/posts/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_posts_index_html_erb__805998677_54338856'
    app/views/posts/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb__805998677_54338856'
    test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:PostsControllerTest>'

bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:4
```

Here is my posts_controller_test.rb:

```
class PostsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get index" do
    get posts_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:posts)  
  end
end
```

The tutorial was produced on an earlier version of rails, which used get:index, which I read is deprecated in rails 5, and the suggestion was to use URL instead of action name.

Interestingly, if I execute the controller home_controller_test.rb, which I have not even modified, I get a different error below:

```
Error:
HomeControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `home_index_url' for #<HomeControllerTest:0x67df790>
    test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:HomeControllerTest>'

bin/rails test test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:4
```

Here is the home_controller_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class HomeControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get index" do
    get home_index_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Any help as to what the issues might be would be much appreciated.

Adding my posts index view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post">
        <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post[:title],post %></h2>
        <div class="entry"><%= post[:body] %></div>
        </br>
        <div class="byline">
            <span class="meta"><%= post[:created_at].strftime("%b %d, %Y") %> Posted By: <%= post.admin_user.name %></span><span class="links"><%= link_to "Read More",post %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Share ur `index` view

Comment: That means, this file: app/views/posts/index.html.erb :)

Comment: I shared my index view above.

Comment: As you can see.. `admin_user` in `post.admin_user` is nil..

Comment: `home_index_url` i think it would be `homes_url`. please check by doing `rake routes` and check whether that helper method exists or not

Answer (score 0):

Update (10 May 2017)

Your Posts model has admin_user_id mostly means Post belongs to AdminUser.

Your development rails app does not trigger the error because it always have linked AdminUser for every post. But in the test environment, you need to setup your database data under test/fixtures folder.

In your case, you need to create a AdminUser (ex. adminUserOne) under test/fixtures/admin_users.yml, and linked your post with the AdminUser like

```
postOne:
  admin_user: adminUserOne
```

then only your post has linked admin_user.

For good practise, may be your just **check the existence** of the AdminUser and giving different output if the admin_user does not exist

```
<%= post.admin_user.present? post.admin_user.name : '-' %>
```

---

For first error

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
>
> app/views/posts/index.html.erb:7

The errror message indicated the error located at the line 7 of the mentioned view file. After refer to your view file content, it is caused by

```
post.admin_user.name
```

Under Post model, it does not have any relationship with admin_user.
Normally we can check the relationship in the db/schema.rb or running rails console with sandbox mode

```
rails c --sandbox
```

then try to do something like

```
Post.first.admin_user
```

to observe what result will be given in the console.

---

For the second error,

The home_index_url is not a valid url in your rails application.

In rails 5, you can use command

```
rails routes -c home
```

to found any related routes. In my application, I have this result

> Prefix
>
> dashboard
>
> root

so I have dashboard_url and root_url. So in your case should have route with prefix home_index then only you can use *home_index_url*.

Comment: Thank you. I see what you are saying now...the Posts model has admin_user_id and not admin_user. So when did execute `Post.first.admin_user` in the console, it is indeed nil. As I mentioned, I am new to RoR and am following a tutorial online. What I don't understand is how `post.admin_user.name` in the view seems to work fine in the browser...the name is actually displayed.

Comment: @henrypj I updated my post, have a check, always beware of possibility of the linked object can be null if do not have any validation before save